# API call in VB.NET much slower than in VB6

Tags: vb.net, performance, vb6

Can somebody explain how it can be that the same API call returns so much quicker with VB6 than with VB.NET?

Here is my VB6 code:

```
Public Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long


Public Function GetWindowTextEx(ByVal uHwnd As Long) As String

Dim lLen&
lLen = GetWindowTextLength(uHwnd) + 1

Dim sTemp$
sTemp = Space(lLen)

lLen = GetWindowText(uHwnd, sTemp, lLen)

Dim sRes$
sRes = Left(sTemp, lLen)

GetWindowTextEx = sRes

End Function
```

And here is my VB.NET code:

```
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpWindowText As String, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer

    Dim sText As String = Space(Int16.MaxValue)
    GetWindowText(hwnd, sText, Int16.MaxValue)
```

I ran each version 1000 times.

The VB6 version needed 2.04893359351538 ms.
The VB.NET version needed 372.1322491699365 ms.

Both Release and Debug version are about the same.

What is happening here?

Comment: Pinvoke does not come for free, it gets outright dangerous when you use the wrong declaration.  Strings in .NET are immutable, your pinvoke call is mutating a string.  You can find proper declarations at pinvoke.net

Comment: Even in VB6 `Declare` is the "slow boat." Using typelibs to establish the linkage bypasses a bit of overhead. I doubt anything can help .Net languages though.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, I would have selected your comment as an answer if you posted it as such. You can still do that, you got great votes. One question, please: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/IsIconic.html The VB.NET declaration seems incomplete to me. Some other functions have this " <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _", but this one has not. Is that because the website is not complete yet, or is there a reason for it?

Comment: You say you ran it 1000 times, but did you ignore the first few runs on the .Net side to account for JIT compilation?  It would be interesting to see your timing method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use the *A version, just skip the suffix, and use StringBuilder instead of String:

```
Private Declare Auto Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpWindowText As StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer

Dim len As Integer = GetWindowTextLength (hwnd)
Dim str As StringBuilder = new StringBuilder (len)
GetWindowText (hwnd, str, str.Capacity)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that declarations would make such a big difference.

Comment: @tmighty: Windows is Unicode internally, so if you use the *A version Windows will have to convert the string between Ansi and Unicode upon entry/exit to GetWindowText. And using StringBuilder makes sure .NET doesn't have to do any string marshalling upon entry/exit either.